# execute logout url in background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m working in a platform based on chamilo LMS. To run properly when the user logged in, a login is made with chamilo in the background using a hidden iframe, now I want to do the logout is similar idea, But I don´t want that the user knows he is logged in  chamilo. I have the path to make de logout, Firstly I try with a hidden iframe but didn´t work because the path is from an input. Now I try using `$.get('path');` but the console returns error for CORS policy. If anyone knows a solution for this or other ideas would be great.

My actual code is:

```
$('#logout').ready(function() {
    $('#logout').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get("logout pat");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As with login and due to CORS, you will need to blindly load the logout path using a hidden iframe:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#logout').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(`<iframe id="logout-frame" src="${logoutPath}" />`)
          .css({display: 'none'})
          .appendTo($('body'));

        // Remove iframe after 500ms
        setTimeout(() => $('#logout-frame').remove(), 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got this error `index.php:478 Blocked autofocusing on a <input> element in a cross-origin subframe.`

Comment: It probably didn't autofocused in the hidden `iframe`, but already downloaded the logout page. Please, check login state.

Comment: Undestood, but the problem is because the path is from an externar url (not form or button) and only need to be clicked to logout. If I click I'm going to be redirect to chamilo's home (thats what I don´t want) and I need to redirect to my platform home

Comment: The only redirected frame is inside the logout hidden frame. It should not affect your web. You can also add a short `setTimeout` to remove the `iframe` a few ms after (ensuring the request gets to the server), removing unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Edited: Change frame id so it does not collides with the button id

Comment: Edited: Add a `setTimeout` to remove the iframe a short time after sending the logout request.